# Problema ao exibir texto com a fonte cv2.QT_FONT_BOLD usando OpenCV em Python

Tags: python, opencv

Estou com problemas para mostrar um texto específico numa imagem, acredito que o problema esteja na fonte utilizada (cv2.QT_FONT_BOLD), pois quando altero a fonte para outra como cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, funciona normalmente.

```
texto = "{}".format(str(round(3.141592*raio*100*fator_conv**2,2))) #cm²
texto2 = "{}".format(str(round(2*raio*fator_conv*100,2))) #cm

cv2.putText(img, texto, (int(cx-0.5*raio),int(cy-0.5*raio)), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 1.5, (0, 0, 255))
cv2.putText(img, texto2, (int(cx-0.5*raio), int(cy+0.5*raio)), cv2.QT_FONT_BOLD, 1.5, (255, 0, 0))
```

O programa mostra o seguinte erro:

```
  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "D:/Projetos/codigos/Detect_HOG+SVM/deteccao_2.py", line 168, in <module>
    cv2.putText(img, texto2, (int(cx-0.5*raio), int(cy+0.5*raio)), cv2.QT_FONT_BOLD, 1.5, (255, 0, 0))
cv2.error: OpenCV(3.4.2) C:\projects\opencv-python\opencv\modules\imgproc\src\drawing.cpp:2216: error: (-211:One of arguments' values is out of range) Unknown font type in function 'cv::getFontData'


Process finished with exit code 1
```

Achei que era porque eu não tinha o pyqt5 instalado no ambiente virtual do Anaconda, instalei e continua igual o erro. Li alguns tutoriais de como usar o qt com python, adicionei

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
```

Mas não deu certo. Alguém tem alguma ideia de onde eu possa estar falhando?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### OpenCV

Ao olhar no [código](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/imgproc/src/drawing.cpp) do `drawing.cpp` e na [documentação](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d6/d6e/group__imgproc__draw.html#ga5126f47f883d730f633d74f07456c576), você pode ver que os parâmetros da função `putText` são:

> Parameters
>
> **img**   Image.
>
> **text**  Text string to be drawn.
>
> **org**   Bottom-left corner of the text string in the image.
>
> **fontFace**  Font type, see [HersheyFonts](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/de1/group__core.html#ga0f9314ea6e35f99bb23f29567fc16e11).
>
> **fontScale** Font scale factor that is multiplied by the font-specific
>   base size.
>
> **color** Text color.
>
> **thickness** Thickness of the lines used to draw a text.
>
> **lineType**  Line type. See [LineTypes](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d0/de1/group__core.html#gaf076ef45de481ac96e0ab3dc2c29a777)
>
> **bottomLeftOrigin**  When true, the image data origin is at the
>   bottom-left corner. Otherwise, it is at the top-left corner.

Exemplo:

`img = cv.putText( img, text, org, fontFace, fontScale, color[, thickness[, lineType[, bottomLeftOrigin]]])`

E no tipo de fonte, uma fonte inválida está sendo utilizada: `cv2.QT_FONT_BOLD`, pois os tipos de fontes aceitos são:

```
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX        | normal size sans-serif font                                          |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_PLAIN          | small size sans-serif font                                           |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_DUPLEX         | normal size sans-serif font (more complex than FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX) |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX        | normal size serif font                                               |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_TRIPLEX        | normal size serif font (more complex than FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX)      |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL  | smaller version of FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX                              |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX | hand-writing style font                                              |
| cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_COMPLEX | more complex variant of FONT_HERSHEY_SCRIPT_SIMPLEX                  |
| cv.FONT_ITALIC                 | flag for italic font                                                 |
```

Para utilizar a fonte da biblioteca Qt, é necessário realizar um link entre o OpenCV e o Qt.

E depois utilizar a função [addText](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga4e2751b94f709c848f0658d78007e449) em conjunto com o [fontQt](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4.0/dc/d46/group__highgui__qt.html#ga6281d0939583c9e0ee36372dfeb52ae3).

`cv.addText(img, text, org, nameFont[, pointSize[, color[, weight[, style[, spacing]]]]])`

### Alternativa

#### PIL

Ou [esta resposta do SOen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37191008/load-truetype-font-to-opencv) fornece uma alternativa com a biblioteca PIL.

```
import numpy as np
from PIL import ImageFont, ImageDraw, Image
import cv2
import time

## Make canvas and set the color
img = np.zeros((200,400,3),np.uint8)
b,g,r,a = 0,255,0,0

## Use cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_XXX to write English.
text = time.strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S %Z", time.localtime()) 
cv2.putText(img,  text, (50,50), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, 0.7, (b,g,r), 1, cv2.LINE_AA)

## Use simsum.ttc to write Chinese.
fontpath = "./simsun.ttc"     
font = ImageFont.truetype(fontpath, 32)
img_pil = Image.fromarray(img)
draw = ImageDraw.Draw(img_pil)
draw.text((50, 100),  "国庆节/中秋节 快乐!", font = font, fill = (b, g, r, a))
img = np.array(img_pil)

## Display 
cv2.imshow("res", img);cv2.waitKey();cv2.destroyAllWindows()
cv2.imwrite("res.png", img)
```

[image: Resultado]

#### Free Type do opencv_contrib

Ou também pode ser utilizado o [Módulo FreeType do OpenCV contrib](https://github.com/opencv/opencv_contrib/tree/master/modules/freetype), em que [loadFontData](https://docs.opencv.org/3.4/d9/dfa/classcv_1_1freetype_1_1FreeType2.html) é usado para carregar um arquivo de fonte e depois pode ser utilizado com a função `putText` do FreeType.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela ajuda! Funcionou aqui, usei a função cv2.addText()